# css border radius box-shadow inset shows a thin edge of the background image

Tags: css, background-image, border

I'm building a white border around an image with a radius. The hover Shows an inset shadow over the white border. It works, only you can see a thin edge of the image in the radius corners, next outside the box-shadow. I tried a border, but the thin edge keeps up showing between the border and the box-shadow. How to prevent that?

```
background-image: url(http://new.urbinaconsulting.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/ocx-promo-block.svg);
background-color: #F5F3F0;
border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
overflow: hidden;
border-width: 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #F5F3F0;
padding-top: 48px;
padding-right: 48px;
padding-bottom: 48px;
padding-left: 48px;
transition: border 300ms ease 0ms,background-color 300ms ease 0ms,background-image 300ms ease 0ms;
-moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 15px rgba(0,0,0,1),inset 0 0 0 10px rgb(245,243,240);
-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 15px rgba(0,0,0,1),inset 0 0 0 10px rgb(245,243,240);
box-shadow: -7px -7px 10px rgba(255,255,255,.98),7px 7px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),0 0 0 10px rgba(245,243,240,.98),inset 0 0 0 10px rgba(245,243,240,.98);
```

[sample image of the error is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekU7H.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try this code

```
 background-image: url(http://new.urbinaconsulting.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/ocx-promo-block.svg);
        background-color: #F5F3F0;
        border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-width: 10px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #F5F3F0;
        padding-top: 48px;
        padding-right: 48px;
        padding-bottom: 48px;
        padding-left: 48px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: -7px -7px 10px rgb(255 255 255 / 98%), 7px 7px 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%), 0 0 0 10px rgb(245 243 240 / 98%);
        box-shadow: -7px -7px 10px rgb(255 255 255 / 98%), 7px 7px 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%), 0 0 0 10px rgb(245 243 240 / 98%);
```

and if you want to add another dark layer inside the border you can add with inset box-shadow

```
    box-shadow: -7px -7px 10px rgb(255 255 255 / 98%), 7px 7px 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%), 0 0 0 10px rgb(245 243 240 / 98%), inset 0 0 13px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 98%)
```

Comment: Hi Shahil, thanks for responding. That doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Hi martin please check this codepen link 

https://codepen.io/sam-123/pen/JjbJYgP

Comment: Hello Shahil, I see in your example that the dark shadow is now next to the border (on the inside). The shadow should cover the border. That is why I also solved the white border with the box-shadow property. That works fine.
What I need help with is that in my example picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekU7H.jpg) you can see that in the corners on the outside of the white border a fraction of the image is visible in the background. I'd like to get rid of that. Do you know a solution for that?

Comment: Hi Martin I tried to replicate your issue and I find out  the thin edge on corners which appears after applying  the border-radius property with inset box-shadow I tried to fid out the solution but didn't  got anything, I don't know why  it behaves  like this so I tried the above code.

Comment: Hi Shahil, it's a strange error. I hope somebody can tell me how to solve that error.